# python 3.8 how to convert txt to csv with seperator of 2 or more spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to convert a txt-export from a telnet session with Python.
The txt looks like this

```
  LocalPort  ChassisId                 PortId PortDescr SysName               

  --------- + ------------------------- ------ --------- ----------------------

  3          01 23 45 67 89 76           1      1         name1

  19         01 23 45 67 89 76           19     19        name2

  21         01 23 45 67 89 76            9      9        name3

  22         01 23 45 67 89 76           22     22        name4

  22         01 23 45 67 89 76           LAN-1  example   name5

  23         01 23 45 67 89 76           LAN-1  example   name6

  23         01 23 45 67 89 76           23     23        name7
```

So I tried something like that with python:

```
read_file = pd.read_csv(OUTPUT_FILE_PROCESSED_TXT, sep="\s{2,}", header=5)
read_file.to_csv(OUTPUT_CSV, sep=",", header=["LocalPort","ChassisId","PortId","PortDescr","SysName"])
```

But the result is that I'm missing a big part between LocalPort 3 and LocalPort 22 in the generated csv. Those lines are removed. So my csv is only the headers and the last three lines.

Can anyone help me and maybe explain why Python is removing some lines?
I know some others asked a similar question but the solutions didn't help me

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `pd.read_csv('your_file.txt', sep='\s\s+')` You may need to add `skiprows=2` also.

Comment: Thank you for that fast reply but the csv has only headers and last 2 lines with these parameters too (Sysname: name6, name7). Everything else is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse that `OUTPUT_FILE_PROCESSED_TXT` file manually:

```
import re

with open(OUTPUT_FILE_PROCESSED_TXT, "r") as f:
    telnet_output = f.read()

rows = telnet_output.splitlines()
values = [re.split(r"\s{2,}", row.strip())  \  # split when >2 spaces
          for row in rows[1:]  \  # avoid header row
          if not row.strip().startswith("-") and row]  # avoid empty and --- rows

columns = rows[0].split()

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)
```

Check that your `df` is well defined:

```
>>> print(df)

  LocalPort          ChassisId PortId PortDescr SysName
0         3  01 23 45 67 89 76      1         1   name1
1        19  01 23 45 67 89 76     19        19   name2
2        21  01 23 45 67 89 76      9         9   name3
3        22  01 23 45 67 89 76     22        22   name4
4        22  01 23 45 67 89 76  LAN-1   example   name5
5        23  01 23 45 67 89 76  LAN-1   example   name6
6        23  01 23 45 67 89 76     23        23   name7
```

And now export to `csv` with what you suggested:

```
df.to_csv(OUTPUT_CSV, sep=",")
```